# Program compiles but does not display GUI on Mac

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So far:

1. I've tried different IDEs-IntelliJ, VS Code, and Net Bean-although I didn't think this was the issue.
2. I tried making the constructor **`TFDemo`** public.
3. I tried running via terminal after compiling.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingDemo {

    SwingDemo() {

        // Create a new JFrame container
        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("A Simple Swing Application");

        // Gives the frame an initial size
        jfrm.setSize(275, 100);

        // Terminate the program when the user closes the application
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create a text-based label
        JLabel jlab = new JLabel(" GUI programming with Swing.");

        // Add the label to the content pane
        jfrm.add(jlab);

        // Display the frame
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the frame on the event dispatching thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           @Override
            public void run() {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `// Gives the frame an initial size` would be more accurate if it read `// Gives the frame a totally guessed, and probably wrong(1) size`. In this case, add an `EmptyBorder` to the `JLabel` and once added, `pack()` the `JFrame`. The frame will then be the minimum size it needs in order to display the label and border. 1) Further, it will be different sizes according to the 'frame decorations' used in each OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't create the frame at the commented block!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create the frame on the event dispatching thread
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       @Override
        public void run() {
           new SwingDemo();
        }
    });
}
```

Also, here it would seem a good idea to let your program exit when you close the primary frame... so add something like,

```
// Add the label to the content pane
jfrm.add(jlab);

// Exit on close
jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

// Display the frame
jfrm.setVisible(true);
```

And running on a mac

[image: Application Screen Shot]